# Hammer.js only triggered in window.onload?

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener, hammer.js, tizen

all

I have a main html And if the notification things happened

I have to show up noti.html and if I click the cancel button in noti.html

I should come back to main html again...

To show noti.html, I changed main.xml 's body tag to noti.html...

And If i click the cancel button I switched again.

But when I come back to main.xml I can't use gesture thing(hammer.js).

It doesn't work because its event-listener is in window.onload function.

So I tried to change event 'load' to 'pageshow'

error occured

like this ... "js/hammer/js  TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'a.addEventListener')"

Does hammer.js event listener only can triggered in onload function???

If it is... any other ideas ?? ...

I want to pop up my notification... without disturbing gesture event listner(hammer.js)...

Help me!! (I'm developing tizen wearable..) Thank you!